# Prove that $f(x)=0$ in $[-1,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(0)=0$ and continuously differentiable in $]-1,1[$. Suppose that 
$$|f'(x)|\leq |f(x)|,\;\mbox{ for all }x\in]-1,1[.$$ 
Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.

My idea is take one point (arbitrary) $x_0>0$ in $]-1,1[$, then using mean value theorem, exist $y_0\in[0,x_0]$ such that

$$|f(y_0)|\geq|f'(y_0)|=\frac{|f(x_0)-f(0)|}{|x_0-0|} \mbox{ then }|f(x_0)|\leq x_0|f(y_0)|,$$

So if $f(y_0)=0$ implies $f(x_0)=0$ and we ended. But is $f(y_0)\neq0$ then I can follow and obtain a decreasing sequence but I not sure that converge to zero.

Thank you by some hints.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis He wants to show that $f$ is **everywhere** $0$.

Comment: Yes, I need prove that $f$ is zero in all the interval $[-1,1]$

Comment: Just iterate your argument and use the fact that $y_0 \le x_0$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x_0>0$. You showed that $|f(x_0)|\le x_0|f(y_0)|$ with $0<y_0<x_0$. With the same steps you can show that $|f(y_0)|\le y_0|f(z_0)|$ with $0<z_0<y_0$. So
$$|f(x_0)|\le x_0|f(y_0)|\le x_0^2|f(z_o)|.$$

Inductively we get $|f(x_0)|\le x_0^n|f(z_n)|$ foer every $n$. $|f(z_n)|$ is definitely bounded by a fixed constant $M$, for example the maximum of $f$ in $[0,x_0]$. Since $|x_0|<1$, then $x_0^n$ goes to $0$, moreover $f(x_0)\le x_0^n M$. This implies that $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: how can be sure $z_n$ tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$?

Comment: Actually that's not important for the proof to work, see the edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Proceeding via contradiction, a repeated application of the MVT produces a decreasing sequence $\{c_{n}\}$ of real numbers bounded below by $0$. By the continuity of $f$, the sequence $\{f(c_{n}) \}$ converges to $0$. But the hypothesis shows that $\{f(c_{n})\}$ is increasing away from $0$, which is a contradiction.